# pinescript on tradingview always plot shape

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

The following simple script plotting the triangle shapes on every bar

and I just wanted to plot shapes only on entry bar and exit bar

```
//@version=4
strategy("XO Trader", overlay=true)

// Define the moving averages
ema12 = ema(close, 12)
ema25 = ema(close, 25)
ma150 = sma(close, 150)

// Calculate the MACD with fast period of 26 and slow period of 100
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 26, 100,9)

// Determine the crossover point
crossBuy = crossover(ema12, ema25)
crossSell = crossunder(ema12, ema25)
var bool enterTrade = false
var bool exitTrade = false
// Create the buy signal
if(crossBuy) 
    if (histLine > 0 and close > ma150) 
        enterTrade := true
                
if (crossSell)
    exitTrade := true
    
plotshape(enterTrade, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar,color=color.green)   
plotshape(exitTrade, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar,color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your booleans `enterTrade` and `exitTrade` are only set to false once, at the beginning of the scrip. 'var' does one-time initialisation.
When they become true, they are never reset to false.
So, remove the two 'var' so the booleans are set to false on every loop.